Recommendations for my plans for a corner broom closet
We want to build a flush triangle corner cabinet for our broom/vacuum.
I feel like we have a good plan but in the same vein of "measure twice, cut once", I wanted to get some input, opinions, and perspective from others.
Below is a rough drawing of what we're trying to achieve.

LB = left back
RB = right back
T = top


So my plan is:

Screw LB and RB board to wall
Cut a triangle piece T that will be secured on top
Inset left and right door with hinges

Zooming in, view from the top (below the T top piece):


For both the LB and RB, cut 45 degrees in on both sides

One for where they will meet in the inside corner
One for where the door will align


For the door, cut 45 degrees on both sides and secure it flush with LB and RB using hinge

This way everything is flush
At most we'll see the hinge unless I can find a way to hide that?



Thoughts? Is anything wrong? Anything I should change?

Bear in mind that corner cabinets often end up with a limited amount of usable space because of the triangular shape. Especially if you're going to store a vacuum in it. Think realistically about what you want it to hold and how you'll store everything - hooks, shelves,etc. For example, place your vacuum in the corner to give you some idea of what size cupboard you'll need just to store the vacuum and go from there. You may need a larger cupboard than you might think.

We have a slim upright vacuum -- kinda like the dyson stick vacs. We've measured out the space so we know it'll fit.

If you're going to "build it in" you only the the part across the front - no need for sides against the walls. Beware of the possibility that your next vacuum might not be the same, or you might not even be able to find one the exact same size as the current one when it dies, so absolute minimum size could come back to bite you.

Some comments to think about...

Walls are rarely perfectly straight so it is unlikely that you can make pre-cut pieces that will fit as tight as you think.
The back corner of the cabinet may need to accommodate the fact that the wall corner most likely has a radius to it. A square corner on the cabinet will not fit tight into the corner.
There may be baseboard or floor corner molding at the bottom that you will have to either modify or work around.
Larger sized panels like you are describing are most likely to be fabricated from plywood. Any wood, and especially plywood, will not finish out well with sharp 45 degree cuts along its edges.
Trying to affix hinges to the thin 45 degree tapered edges is doomed to be a total nightmare and subject to early failure.

I personally think you would be better off planning your cabinet design a bit differently so that your door actually has square corners. You should also plan your door to be fitted to a frame which you install first and secure to the walls. If done with proper design you can scribe the side rails on either side to the wall and then cut & plane to get the nice fit that you would want.
Here is a top view of a recommendation on how to construct one front corner:

Cut all your side panels with square corners including the back corner.
Use clear finer grade wood for the narrow backer strips and the scribed to wall frame pieces. Assemble all in place before even thinking of fitting the door. The cut the door to get the fit that you want.
Here is a 3D view of the concept. Details for the top not included here.

The "backer strip" is a wood piece cut to join to the square edge of the side panel, provide a surface to mount the frame trim piece to and also perform a stop for the door to close against. The "frame trim piece" is a wood strip that is initially cut a bit wider than needed and then scribed its full height to get a line that conforms to the wall. Cutting and using a plane on this piece to the line will allow there to be a very nice tight fit to the walls.
For the "hidden door hinge" you want to use an internal "euro style" cabinet hinge. These come in many styles based in part how they are mounted and whether the door is inset (like proposed here) or mounts on the outside of the face frame.

Can you elaborate on #5? Why? And I get your drawing. What does backer strip and frame scribe piece mean?

@IMTheNachoMan #5 because you need to screw your hinge to this little wedge of wood, which is gonna be a pretty weak connection.  Also, because in your sketch the hinge is exposed.

Where would the hinge go so that it can be hidden?

@IMTheNachoMan - Hopefully the additional information I added to my answer explains things better for you.

It does. Thank you so much. We want two doors so I'm tweaking your design but I think it'll work well. Thank you!
